# Which program should I use for programming apps with relational and graph databases?

Tags: windows, software-development, programming, linux-distribution

I'm about to change my PC OS to some Linux distribution, and I wanna continue programming in some environment similar to Visual Studio/SQL Server for designing my apps.

I want you to help me with some suggestions of what linux distro is the best for programming and which program should I use for developing my apps. I would like to use some 'drag-and-drop' GUI designers (like VS or Netbeans), and with the feature to export my apps to Windows and MacOS.

I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! I'd say the Linux *distro* is the less relevant part of your question. You'd better ask for the GUI designer you want to use (specifying your requirements towards it) that should run "on Linux". It's rather rare that such an application is bound to a specific Linux distro. It *might* be bound to a specific desktop environment, though (e.g. KDE or Gnome). But those dependencies are usually available on most Linux distros again. As pointed out, you need to specify your requirements for good and matching answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

## Xojo

[*Xojo*](http://www.xojo.com/), formerly known as *REALBasic*, is an integrated set of advanced tools including a programming language, a sophisticated visual drag-and-drop GUI layout editor, and multi-platform compilers. Think of Xojo as [Visual Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic?wprov=sfsi1) reborn and vastly improved.

Xojo is easy enough for a beginner to learn programming but also powerful enough for daily use by professional developers. The language is fully object-oriented and uses modern compiler technology. Comes with thorough documentation, both reference and tutorial.

The development tools run on several Linux distros, Microsoft Windows and macOS.

### Desktop apps

Desktop apps deploy to those 3 platforms (Linux/Win/Mac) as well as [deploying](http://www.xojo.com/raspberrypi/) to [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi). See the [System Requirements](http://www.xojo.com/) page for details.

### Web apps

You can also build web apps, without needing to learn HTML, CSS, JavaScript, DOM, and such. Amazing technology: Your app executes in Xojo on the server-side but renders automagically on the client-side in a web browser using standard web technologies (no plugins).

### iOS apps

You can also build iOS apps, but only when running Xojo on macOS with access to [Xcode](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode).

### Database

Xojo supports a variety of databases, including: SQLite, [PostgreSQL](https://xojo.com/resources/postgre.php), MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server and Oracle. See the page, [*Xojo and databases*](https://www.xojo.com/resources/databases.php).

By the way, [here is a fresh article](https://appdevelopermagazine.com/4392/2016/9/14/Xojo-2016-Release-3-Ships-With-Loads-of-New-Features-for-Making-Apps/) about Xojo 2016 Release 3 shipping.

The [Xojo Developer Conference (XDC)](http://www.xojo.com/xdc/) is next month in Houston TX.

Comment: Powerful weapon! Installing it. Thanks @Basil Bourque !